# Finding the query that created a table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am a new employee at the company. The person before me had built some tables in BigQuery. I want to investigate the create table query for that particular table.

Things I would want to check using the query is:

1. What joins were used?
2. What are the other tables used to make the table in question?

I have not worked with BigQuery before but I did my due diligence by reading tutorials and the documentation. I could not find anything related there.

Comment: This is not really about SQL. I think you will have more luck if you add Google Cloud tags to your question.

Comment: Did you check out https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/

Comment: BigQuery allows you to create tables from various data sources, including just plain files from GCS or similar. So you don't have to define the schema up-front or with joins like regular database, it can be inferred from input data.

Comment: @Hitobat Thanks. I changed it. I am not sure how that tag got changed to sql.

Comment: @Hitobat I agree. But I just want to know what was used when the other person made those tables. I see in the documentation that tables can be a result of queries. It would be great if I can see what queries led to this table creation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brief outline of your actions below:

Step 1 - gather all query jobs of that user using [Jobs.list API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list) - you must have Is Owner permission for respective projects to get someone else's jobs

Step 2 - extract only  those jobs run by the [`user`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list#jobs.user_email) you mentioned and referencing your table of interest - using [`destination table`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list#jobs.configuration.query.destinationTable) attribute

Step 3 - for those extracted jobs - just simply check respective [`queries`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list#jobs.configuration.query.query) which allow you to learn how that table was populated

Hth!

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for an answer since a long time.
Finally found it :
Go to the three bars tab on the left hand side top

From there go to the Analytics tab.

Select BigQuery under which you will find Scheduled queries option,click on that.

In the filter tab you can enter the keywords and get the required query of the table.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was able to go through my query history and find the query I used.

Step 1.

Go to the Bigquery UI, on the bottom there are `personal history` and `project history` tabs. If you can use the same account used to execute the query I recommend `personal history`.

Step 2.

Click on the tab and there will be a list of queries ordered from most recently run. Check the time the table was created and find a query that ran before the table creation time.

Since the query will run first and create the table there will be slight differences. For me it stayed between a few seconds.

Step 3.

After you find the query used to create the table, simply copy it. And you're done.