# Copy table structure alone in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

In Google's Big query, is there a way to clone (copy the structure alone) a table without data?

bq cp doesn't seem to have an option to copy structure without data. 
And Create table as Select (CTAS) with filter such as "1=2" does create the table without data. But, it doesn't copy the partitioning/clustering properties.

Comment: please check the suggestion given in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371881/finding-the-query-that-created-a-table-in-bigquery)

Comment: CREATE TABLE myNewTable LIKE myExistingTable

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to clone structure of table along with partitioning/clustering properties w/o having need in knowing what exactly those partitioning/clustering properties - follow below steps:

**Step 1**: just copy `your_table` to new table - let's say `your_table_copy`. This will obviously copy whole table including all properties (including such like descriptions, partition's expiration etc. - which is very simple to miss if you will try to set them manually) and data. Note: copy is cost free operation

**Step 2**: To get rid of data in newly created table - run below query statement

```
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.your_table_copy` LIMIT 0
```

while running above make sure you set `project.dataset.your_table_copy` as destination table with 'Overwrite Table' as 'Write Preference'.  Note: this is also cost free step (because of LIMIT 0)

You can easily do both above steps from within Web UI or Command Line or API or any client of your choice  - whatever you are most comfortable with

Comment: How does SELECTing clear the data? I would have expected DELETE.

Comment: I see. You are saying that this SELECT statement serves as the source of the copying; with overwrite, this means deletion of the destination.

Comment: this is a terrible idea if the table in question has > 1 petabyte data and you only want to copy the schema

Comment: only works if both the tables on same data location

Answer (score 30):

BigQuery now supports `CREATE TABLE LIKE` explicitly for this purpose.

See documentation linked below:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_like

Comment: This one worked for me pretty well.! Thanks

Comment: This should be accepted answer

Comment: I get `Syntax error: Unexpected keyword LIKE`

Answer (score 18):

You can use DDL and limit 0, but you need to express partitioning and clustering in the query as well

```
#standardSQL
 CREATE TABLE mydataset.myclusteredtable
 PARTITION BY DATE(timestamp)
 CLUSTER BY
   customer_id
 AS SELECT * FROM mydataset.myothertable LIMIT 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Drawback with this approach is, it is not possible to create an ingestion-time partitioned table from the result of a query.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not copy NULLABLE mode on columns

Answer (score 13):

This is possible with the [BQ CLI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool).

First download the schema of the existing table:

```
bq show --format=prettyjson project:dataset.table | jq '.schema.fields' > table.json
```

Then, create a new table with the provided schema and required partitioning:

```
bq mk \
  --time_partitioning_type=DAY \
  --time_partitioning_field date_field \
  --require_partition_filter \
  --table dataset.tablename \
  table.json
```

See more info on `bq mk` options: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables

Install [jq](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jq) with: `npm install node-jq`

Comment: definitely better than the accepted solution, thumbs up

Answer (score 2):

You can use BigQuery [API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) to run a select, as you suggested, which will return an empty result and set the partition and cluster fields.

This is an example (Only partition but cluster works as well)

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/myProject/jobs' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"configuration":{"query":{"query":"SELECT * FROM `Project.dataset.audit` WHERE 1 = 2","timePartitioning":{"type":"DAY"},"destinationTable":{"datasetId":"datasetId","projectId":"projectId","tableId":"test"},"useLegacySql":false}}}' \
  --compressed
```

**Result**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I went with below python script to detect the schema/partitioning/clustering properties to re-create(clone) the clustered table without data. I hope we get an out of the box feature from bigquery to clone a table structure without the need for a script such as this.

```
import commands
import json

BQ_EXPORT_SCHEMA = "bq show --schema --format=prettyjson %project%:%dataset%.%table% > %path_to_schema%"
BQ_SHOW_TABLE_DEF="bq show --format=prettyjson %project%:%dataset%.%table%"
BQ_MK_TABLE = "bq mk --table --time_partitioning_type=%partition_type% %optional_time_partition_field% --clustering_fields %clustering_fields% %project%:%dataset%.%table% ./%cluster_json_file%"


def create_table_with_cluster(bq_project, bq_dataset, source_table, target_table):

    cmd = BQ_EXPORT_SCHEMA.replace('%project%', bq_project)\
        .replace('%dataset%', bq_dataset)\
        .replace('%table%', source_table)\
        .replace('%path_to_schema%', source_table)
    commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)

    cmd = BQ_SHOW_TABLE_DEF.replace('%project%', bq_project)\
        .replace('%dataset%', bq_dataset)\
        .replace('%table%', source_table)
    (return_value, output) = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)

    bq_result = json.loads(output)

    clustering_fields = bq_result["clustering"]["fields"]
    time_partitioning = bq_result["timePartitioning"]
    time_partitioning_type = time_partitioning["type"]
    time_partitioning_field = ""
    if "field" in time_partitioning:
        time_partitioning_field = "--time_partitioning_field " + time_partitioning["field"]

    clustering_fields_list = ",".join(str(x) for x in clustering_fields)

    cmd = BQ_MK_TABLE.replace('%project%', bq_project)\
        .replace('%dataset%', bq_dataset)\
        .replace('%table%', target_table)\
        .replace('%cluster_json_file%', source_table)\
        .replace('%clustering_fields%', clustering_fields_list)\
        .replace('%partition_type%', time_partitioning_type)\
        .replace('%optional_time_partition_field%', time_partitioning_field)
    commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)


create_table_with_cluster('test_project', 'test_dataset', 'source_table', 'target_table')
```

Answer (score 1):

Somebody mentioned `LIKE` in another answer, but the syntax wasn't clear from the provided answer alone, hence an example below:

```sql
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_id.dataset.table_name_copy` 
   LIKE `project_id.dataset.table_name_original`;
```