# How copy a table to an empty dataset in a new bigquery project?

Tags: google-bigquery

There are two bigquery projects: proj1 and proj2
proj2 is created recently and is empty. Proj1 has dataset1 and it has a table called table1. I want to create same table for proj2 (same schema with no data).
I created dataset2 for proj2.
I clicked on the copy table in the (proj1:dataset1)table1 and chose proj2 and dataset2 as destination and table2 as table name. When I click on copy it gives error:
Not found: proj2:Dataset2

I am not sure what is the best way to copy schema but my approch was following this: copying the table and then empty it
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54053998/copy-table-structure-alone-in-bigquery][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bq cp` command:

```
bq cp project1:dataset.table project2:dataset.table
```

If you are willing to copy all tables:

```
bq mk --transfer_config \
      --project_id=target-project \
      --data_source=cross_region_copy \
      --target_dataset=target-dataset \
      --display_name='Dataset Copy' \
      --params='{"source_dataset_id":"source-dataset","source_project_id":"source-project"}'
```

Comment: You can use a different name for the table in target dataset/project !