# How to create a new BigQuery Table using the Java API that copies a structure from another table?

Tags: java, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I is possible to use the "like" keyword for a sql query. But how can I do it from java?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
destination_table LIKE source_table;
```

This is NOT a copy of this question: [Copy table structure alone in Bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54053998/copy-table-structure-alone-in-bigquery)

I want to perform the LIKE operation from the java api. The question above does that only with sql.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy table structure alone in Bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54053998/copy-table-structure-alone-in-bigquery)

Comment: You want to execute this query from a Java program ?

Comment: @nbk. No it does not. I need a java solution. In your question there are only sql and python solutions.

Comment: @MazlumTosun I would like to use the java BQ api preferably. But executing the query could also help.

Comment: if the orm you are using doesn't support this, you can always run the raw query, implement an extension for an orm is possible, but basically you only build a wrapper for the raw code, so no need to to it the hard way

Comment: Why don't you run your query with BigQuery Java client library?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i want to know if there is a java library function for that. But running a raw query might be a temporary alternative

Comment: If you want to know of there is "a java library function" for that then I suggest you use the search function in the documentation ...

Comment: @arkascha I havent found any. Thats why I am here. Probably there is none and I wanted to hear from the smart people how they would do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "I havent found any"? Of course there is a documentation and it is extensive and complete: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators?hl=en

Comment: @arkascha As I mentioned in the question i am not seraching for an SQL solution. As you see I HAVE the desired sql script for. I was serching for a Java solution. And I actually found one by myself using com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery

Answer (score 1):

I see only 2 solutions:

1. Perform an API call (with the client libraries or the API directly, no difference, the client library is a API call wrapper) to [insert a query job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert). And put your create table query in it (the easiest)
2. You can extract the schema of the source table and use the [insert table API call](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert) (with or without the client library) to insert a new table with the same schema as the source table (don't forget to also copy the partition, retention, and other non schema related attribute from source to add them to the target)